# Android Graphical Layout Editor Not Showing Previews

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just installed Eclipse/ADT on one of my other computers, and everything is fine, except for the graphical layout editor. For some reason, the graphical layout component previews are not showing up like they normally do, just text.

I have it set to show previews, however, I am only seeing text and this is very odd.

Anyone know why this is?

Picture for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because of **API Level 19**, *Android 4.4.x* **KitKat** doesn't support **Show Previews** in Eclipse ADT.

Try changing **API Level** to below **19**.